# Count if there are information between strings

Tags: php

I'm writing a script in PHP to generate a report from a log file out of a telecomunication center. I managed to count the total number of phone calls (received, dialed and not answered), but I strugled to count missed and completed phone calls by themselves.

Here's what I have to count all phone calls. 
The log files give me these information:

```
L1---> Start: 01/08/2017 11:44:32 <br>
L1  6735098700  6735098700  -   -   -   01/08/2017 11:44:32<br>
L1  6735098700  6735098700  -   -   -   01/08/2017 11:44:32<br>
L1  6735098700  6735098700  -   -   -   01/08/2017 11:44:32<br>
L1  6735098700  6735098700  -   -   -   01/08/2017 11:44:33<br>
L1<--- End: 01/08/2017 11:44:40
```

All I did was count the number of occurencies of the word Start, which means a call was started.

```
<?php

    if ($text = @file("files/report.txt")) {
        $rpt = implode ("",$text);
        echo substr_count($rpt, 'Start');
    }else{
        echo "<h3>There's no file to read in the directory</h3>";
    }

?>
```

Now I need to count when a call wasn't answered, which shows on the log files as bellow:

```
L1---> Start: 01/08/2017 11:45:15
L1<--- End: 01/08/2017 11:45:16
```

With no content between the L1--> Start and L1<-- End mark. And I also need to count all completed phone calls which is simply TOTAL CALLS - MISSED CALLS.

Can anyone give an idea on how to manage this?

Thanks.

Comment: Using `file()` then `implode("",..)` is equals to [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: Iterate over each line. Check if it has `Start`, if it does - count following lines until `End`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to match the number of times a line starts with `L1---> Start and L1<--- End` just like you said for the number of missed calls.

```
preg_match_all('/L1--->\sStart:\s([\d\/\s:]+)L1<---\sEnd/', $rpt, $matches);
```

Then, to get the count, it's going to be:

```
count($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Done it! Thanks again.

Comment: @AlanKelvin Np! :)